# Akka logging resets during shutdown

Tags: akka

Under Akka 2.10 my logging configuration is being reset during shutdown... resulting in potentially-important messages being written to standard output rather than the logging mechanism.

For example, this code:

```
String settings =
        "akka.event-handlers = [\"akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler\"]\n" +
        "akka.actor.provider = \"akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider\"";
Config config = ConfigFactory.parseString(settings);
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("testing", config);
LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(system, new Object());
log.info("Via SlF4J");
system.shutdown();
Thread.sleep(1000);
log.info("After shutdown");
```

Produces this output:

```
17:24:11.999 [testing-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler - Slf4jEventHandler started
17:24:12.151 [testing-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  N.168.1.106:2552) - RemoteServerStarted@akka://testing@192.168.1.106:2552
17:24:12.155 [testing-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  java.lang.Object - Via SlF4J
[INFO] [04/12/2013 17:24:12.218] [testing-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [NettyRemoteTransport(akka://testing@192.168.1.106:2552)] RemoteServerShutdown@akka://testing@192.168.1.106:2552
[INFO] [04/12/2013 17:24:13.156] [main] [Object(akka://testing)] After shutdown
```

The first three lines of output are via SLF4J (my configured logger), whereas the final two are via `akka.event.Logging$StandardOutLogger` -- which means that exceptions being logged during shutdown (and I am seeing a few, in some circumstances) are being lost to the logger.

(It would also be nice to see the RemoteServerShutdown message logged correctly, of course.)

Anybody have any insight into this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to be resolved by upgrading to Akka 2.10-2.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Akka’s logging is built upon actors, and naturally since all actors are shut down during `ActorSystem.shutdown()` it must stop working at some point. The fallback to console logging has been put in place so that messages logged really late are still not completely lost.

What you are seeing is that your `log.info` sometimes comes in before and sometimes after the point in time when logging is shut down, since `ActorSystem.shutdown()` merely initiates the shutdown which then proceeds asynchronously.

Thus the conclusion is that logging via the actor system should be done only from within the actor system, since that ensures that things are still up and running.

Comment: Thank you -- and I agree with what you're saying -- but the problem is that Akka is logging *its own* messages (incorrectly) after shutdown (e.g. "RemoteServerShutdown").  My "log.info" was only added to confirm that the change in logging was related to timing. (I have no need to log such a message -- but I do have a need for Akka to correctly log its own!)